# Splunk eventstats dc(field) is including null values as unique

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I need to count distinct values not including null values

```
Field
ABC
CBA
BCA
null
null
null
```

I need `| eventstats dc(field) as "field_count"` to return 3, but it returns 4. I can't use the `allnum=true` as the data is a list of strings, not numbers. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you filter out NULLs prior to aggregation?

Answer (score 1):

The value "`null`" is not "null"

A "null" field in Splunk has no contents (see [`fillnull`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Fillnull))

If you have the literal string "`null`" in your field, it has a value (namely, "`null`")

If you do not want to count them, you need to filter them out before doing the `| stats dc(Field)`

For example, you could do this:

```
<spl>
| search NOT Field="null"
| stats dc(Field) 
<spl>
```